# Using Three.js with HtmlUnit giving error

Tags: java, three.js, xmlhttprequest, htmlunit

While using HtmlUnit for rendering 3d interactive canvas with three.js, I got the following error:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function overrideMimeType in object [object XMLHttpRequest].
```

Is XMLHttpRequest supported by HtmlUnit? Is WebGL supported by HtmlUnit?